# why is $\exists z \forall x \forall y (x-y=z+2)$ false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

In the rational numbers Q, is it true that:
$$ \exists z \forall x \forall y \space (x-y=z+2) $$
This question showed up on my last test in discrete mathematics, and I have no idea why the right answer is that it is false.

Is it not possible to set $ z = x - y - 2 $ and conclude that such a $z$ will always exist in Q?

I am probably missing something pretty fundamental, can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: It says there exists one $z$ which satisfies the equation for all $x$ and for all $y$.  So you can set $z=x-y-2$ for some $x,y$, but it doesn't hold for all $x,y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer would be correct if the assertion was$$\forall x\forall y\exists z(x-y=z+2)$$because your $z$ depends upon $x$ and $y$. But the assertion$$\exists z\forall x\forall y(x-y=z+2)$$means that there is a rational number $z$ such that. for **every** rational $x$ and **every** rational $y$, $z+2=x+y$. And, clearly, no such number exists.

Comment: Tank you so much, seems like I was really missing something fundamental as I didn't know there was any difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion tells that $z$ is fixed. it doesn't depend neither of $x$ nor of $y$.

assume it exists.

then

$$1-1=z+2$$ and
$$1-0=z+2$$

what is the conclusion.